# My Css for Background Color Won't Fill Entire Section

Tags: css, background, background-color

The site is supposed to be a scrolling parallax website with several fixed background image. In this particular problem section, I have two divs next to each other. the top one has a fixed background image with h2 text. Its kind of supposed to serve as a header of sorts for the bottom div that contains my info text. For some reason, when i set the background color on the info text div, there remains a thin white space between the bottom of the fixed image div and the top of the info text div.

i know that stuff like this can be caused by margins collapsing so i have tried the following:

I tried setting margins to 0px(also 1px), taking out all margins and using padding instead, setting all padding to 0px and 1px, changing the image size, and changing the image height. Nothing has worked.

```css
.aboutme {
  background: url('../img/aboutme11.png') no-repeat;
  font: 'Century Gothic';
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 800%;
}

.aboutmetxt {
  font-size: 150%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="paralax1" class="aboutme">
  <h2 style="font-size:100%; padding-top:50px;">About Me
    <h2>
</div>

<div id="aboutme" class="aboutmetxt">
  <p> I am a self taught Front end developer and Graphic Designer Currently Located in Los Angeles California. I am pursuing an opportunity to began a career in Web Development. This responsive website site was one of my first projects. I built using the
    skills I have learned from programing in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I Currently attend California State University Northridge and am finishing my BA in Graphis Design with a minor in Computer Science.     </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Prepare the working code here or using this page https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: im sorry, im fairly new to this site, you want me to post my current code in this comment section?

Comment: He is asking for you to add a working example of the code in your question in JSFiddle. Also, can you please accept the current edit that has been submitted? (or decline it and allow me to edit it :D)

Comment: Ok i think i did it.. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/0mnzgrbs/1/

Comment: the fixed images aren't appearing so its hard to see whats happening. but if you scroll down, you see the text. there's supposed to be a window right above the text with a fixed background image but there's a white space between the two sections.

Comment: Welcome in! You can add your codes to the snippet, it will make it easy for people to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's many, many mistakes within your code, from incorrect spelling in the about me text to using the wrong CSS Property. So, I tried to fix all of them...

Here's your original code: https://jsfiddle.net/tvdchajo/1/

Here's the new code (I know most people just want the code rather than the explanation.)

```css
.aboutme {
  background: url('../img/aboutme11.png'), no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  position: relative;
  min-height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 800%;
}

.aboutmetxt {
  font-size: 150%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

body {
  background-color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<div id="paralax1" class="aboutme">
  <h2 style="font-size:100%; padding-top:50px;">
    About Me
  </h2>
</div>

<div id="aboutme" class="aboutmetxt">
  <p> I am a self taught Front-End Developer and Graphics Designer. I am currently located in Los Angeles, California. I am pursuing an opportunity to begin a career in Web Development. This responsive website site was one of my first projects. I built using the
    skills I have learned from programming in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I'm currently attending 'California State University, Northridge' and I'm finishing my BA in Graphics &  Design with a minor in Computer Science. 
  </p>
</div>
```

So basically, all I did here was give `body {` the background colour you used for the `.aboutmetxt {`.

Here's another JSFiddle of my version of your webpage: https://jsfiddle.net/tvdchajo/2/

Use VW and VH for responsive websites. They're two very useful CSS Units.

Comment: So that fixed the white space but something else broke. So behind the fixed background image that precedes the about me text box, There's another fixed background image. this is the first thing you see before you scroll down and the about me fixed image window comes up followed by the text. The first image is centered and fixed but for some reason when i add the background color to the body tag adding the image is no longer center or fixed and moves with the top of the about me image window. Its kinda hard to describe but i hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did you see my version of your webpage? https://jsfiddle.net/tvdchajo/2/

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle using your code and made some edits to it I hope it helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/1npm4g2j/18/

I left your html alone for the most part:

**HTML**

```
<div id="paralax1" class="aboutme" >
 <h2>About Me<h2>
</div>

<div id="aboutme" class="aboutmetxt">
 <p> I am a self taught Front end developer and Graphic Designer Currently Located
  in Los Angeles California. I am pursuing an opportunity to began a career in
 Web Development. This responsive website site was one of my first projects.
 I built using the skills I have learned from programing in JavaScript, HTML and CSS.
 I Currently attend California State University Northridge and am finishing my
 BA in Graphis Design with a minor in Computer Science.</p>
</div>
```

Your css is where I made the most changes:

**CSS**

```
html{
 background-color: #323232;
 height: 110vh;

overflow: scroll;
}

.aboutme{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;

 top: 5%;
 left: 15%;

 background:url('../img/aboutme11.png') no-repeat;
 font:'Century Gothic';

 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;

 min-height: 25%;
 color:#fff;
}

.aboutmetxt{
 font-size: 150%;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 0px 80px;
 background-color: #323232;
 color:#f2f2f2;
}

h2{
 font-size: 126px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for responding but unfortunately that kinda broke everything. The fixed image was no longer spanning the width of the page but was off to the right ad the white space was still there..